# how can I prevent native facebook login dialog in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am using facebooksdk.framework 3.1

when I login my app with my account, native login dialog pops up even though web based auth 
completed.  I need to turn off either native login dialog or web based auth but I don't know how.

I tried to find facebook.m file but there was no such file on facebooksdk.framework 3.1

how do I turn off safariauth or native auth?? It is very strange two login process occurs at the
same time.

Comment: There should be something wrong either in your implementation or facebook.m. I once developed for android and it's logic was if there is native use native, web other-wise. No chance for both of them trigger.

Comment: And @Seho Lee, please post the line of code you are using to login into facebook.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you use phonegap facebook plugin, you should call FB.getLoginStatus() carefully.

If FB.getLoginStatus() fires before FB.init() is done, the function would return a response as

'not connected' even if user is already connected.

my login problem was due to FB.getLoginStatus() on my redirected page.

even if user succed login and procceded to my redirected page, the page run FB.getLoginStatus()

and result was always 'not connected' because FB.init() not completely executed.

facebook provides async function to solve this problem but it didn't work when I tested on phonegap.

to check user login, I use FB.Event.subscribe and localstorage for now.

on the page that needs FB functions, I added this javascript code

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response){
    localStorage.setItem('fblogin', true);
    console.log('login event');
}
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response){
    localStorage.setItem('fblogin', false);
    console.log('logout event');
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
 try{
      FB.init({ appId : '1234567889' , nativeInterface : CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs : true});
 }catch(e){
      alert(e);
 }
 var fbval = localStorage.getItem('fblogin');
 if(fbval){
     // your code for connected status
 }
});
```

basically, I set 'fblogin' localStorage value true whenever login event occurs, 
 
and set the value 'false' whenever logout event occurs. 
by comparing 'fblogin' value, I check users are logged or not.

Answer (score 1):

First of all go to facebook.m page & try to find the following method:

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions
         delegate:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate
       localAppId:(NSString *)localAppId
```

in this method there is a line:`[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:NO];`

change authorizeWithFBAppAuth & safariAuth to yes/no according to your need.Hope it helps you.

Or you can try to implement latest Share kit sdk.it is best way.